# Mongo Aggregate: failed to query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
const {pageIndex, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder, filters} = data;
        
    return  Voter.aggregate([
    {
            $match: {
                isVoterVerified: false
            },
            $facet: {
                metadata: [{$count: "total"}, {$addFields {page:pageIndex}}],
                data: [
                    {
                        $sort: {
                            [sortField || "createdAt"]: sortOrder || -1,
                        },
                    },
                    {$skip: (pageSize * (pageIndex - 1)) || 0},
                    {$limit: pageSize},
                ],
            },
        }
    ]).exec();
```

Postman
[image: Postmen]

I want to get all of the entries based on "isVoterVerified = false" and add pagination.
when I run on postmen or in web client, I get an error saying  "bad request".
However, if I remove one of the stages and run it works perfectly fine.

I want to match the entries "isVoterVerified = false" and add pagination.

Comment: You're missing a pair of curly brackets. Each object in the array should be a single aggregation stage. Right now you've got one object with both of the stages inside. Close the $match and open a new object for the $facet

Comment: I did not notice this. 
thank you @ray